# Gimp "Text to Path" on Strange Shapes

Tags: text, path, gimp

I'm trying to duplicate an 1800's style sign using Gimp, and am really struggling with text to path.

Here's an example image: http://designobserver.com/media/images/02.02.14.17_525.jpg

I've been using Gimp for years, but when it comes to making text follow curves, it seems really challenging, and the results somewhat arbitrary.

Can anyone point me to some good tutorials that are more complex than simple text on an oval?

Part of my issue is just being able to manipulate the path properly. I can't seem to edit the path once it's created. The keyboard shortcuts Alt and Cntrl don't work, and choosing the radio buttons from the menu don't work either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to this problem, for those struggling with the same thing.

Instead of using the text to path, you want to use a different tool

First, create some text, and stay on the layer. From the menus, select:

```
Filters -> Distorts -> Curve Bend
```

Then you'll have the option to create two curving lines-- one for the top of the text (Upper), and one for the bottom (Lower).

It's really quite easy, though it may take a bit of experimentation to get the exact look you're going for. It's much more powerful than using the path tool.

Good luck!